# Write a corresponding predicate logic sentences for the following "Some sleepy students do not answer any question."?

Tags: discrete-mathematics, logic, recreational-mathematics, predicate-logic

My answer is that

> Let $A$ represent a student that answers any question, and let $S$ represent a sleepy student. Then, $\exists x (S(x)\wedge \neg A(x))$.

Is it correct?

Comment: It's as correct as saying that it is $P$, where $P$ denotes the predicate "Some sleepy students do not answer any question".

Comment: Presumably, you have to use a "universe" with Students and Questions; if so, you have to use more predicates: Student(x), Question(y), Sleepy(z) and Answer(x,y).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Exists x with (x is sleepy student and
not for all q, (q is question implies x answers q)),

which is equivalent to

Exists x with (x is sleepy student and
exist q with (q is question and not-(x answers q)).

However “Some sleepy students do not answer any question.”
is liguishically awkward.
"Some sleepy students do not answer any questions.”
does not have that semantic difficulty but has a different meaning.  Namely:

Exists x with (x is sleepy student and
for all q, (q is question implies not-(x answers q))).

Comment: thank you all for he help

Comment: See edit.  @DR . .

Comment: William Elliot Tnks broo